# Generate order number

Tags: c#, sql-server, identity

I have a requirement that I need to generates an order number that should be shown to user before giving the order.

I thought to use identity column of database but it is not correct as MSDN says

> Be cautious about using IDENT_CURRENT to predict the next generated
>   identity value. The actual generated value may be different from
>   IDENT_CURRENT plus IDENT_INCR because of insertions performed by other
>   sessions.

Should  I create another column for order number but here i need to manage the uniqueness of order id.

So what would be the best alternative to do this.

Comment: How about using a sequence (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)

Comment: The **best** way is to just let SQL Server handle the `IDENTITY` column - let SQL Server handle the details, and don't try to "guess" the IDENTITY value ahead of time. Just don't - stop trying.

Comment: "that should be shown to user before giving the order." - what happens if they decide not to place an order?

Comment: You should create the order record and return the Identity column value as the order number.  If the user decides not to go ahead with the order then you can delete the record or flag it as incomplete. As you mentioned, trying to predict the next order number is unreliable.

Comment: @AakashM delete the record or have a house keeping routine that tidies up "draft" records periodically

Comment: Usually such confirmation numbers are given after the user has given the last confirmation. The best practice would be to insert the unique record (whether just using running ID's or uniqueidentifiers) into SQL Server and then return that back to the user. Otherwise you'll have to come up with some gimmicky way of creating unique order numbers while still making sure they don't clash after the transaction is committed. There is no other way for SQL Server to keep track of several uncommitted transactions and avoid duplicates ahead of time.

Comment: @csl so it's OK to have gaps in the number sequence?

Comment: @AakashM of course - I tend to have a status against each order so instead of deleting I would create it as "Draft" or "New" and then if incomplete I just set the status to "Cancelled" that way I can report on all the orders that have ever been created.

Comment: @csl are you sure that's the case for the asker's business rules?

Comment: @AakashM the only requirement that is explicitly mentioned is "I have a requirement that I need to generates an order number that should be shown to user before giving the order." It is not mentioned anywhere that it has to be sequential. I think you are over thinking this somewhat.

Comment: @csl actually I'm not thinking about it at all. I'm suggesting the *asker* needs to consider what should happen when the user decides not to place an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what point do you need to generate the order number?  I would usually add the order record to the database and retrieve the ID assigned to that row.  This would then be used as the order number, perhaps padding it out to a particular number of digits or adding some alpha characters to the front.  For example, a row added with ID 42 might be formatted as the order number "ORD000042".

Answer (score 3):

add a field called "OrderNumber" on the level of customer table and by default set to 0 ( assuming that each customer doesn't has an order yet)

on creating new order you can add the order Id as ( Letter O + Customer Id + OrderNumber +1) 
and on saving the order increment the OrderNumber in the table customer by 1 for the given customer

example:

```
table customer(cid,name,...,orderNumber)
table order(oid,cid,total,date,code)

on creating new order => code= string.Format("O{0}-{0:0000}",cid,orderNumber+1)

on saving the order => update customer set orderNumber=orderNumber+1 where cid=*customer id*
```

this way you can track all the orders per customer for example customer 100 has 3 orders =>
the new order code will be O100-00004

and the customer 109 which has already 15 orders => the new order code will be O109-00016

and so on

regards